# How does randomized hashing defeat collision attack?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, randomness

SEC#1 recommends randomized hashing when using SHA-1 with ECDSA; SPHINCS+ uses randomized hashing in WOTS+ to defeat collision attack so as to reduce signature size.

How does a randomized hashing defeat collision attack? What are the limitations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In randomized hashing for Merkle-Damgard based hash function (like MD5, SHA1, SHA2) the input preprocessed with a salt before hashing applied. This process doesn't modify the underlying hash function uses it as a black box, It is proposed by Shai Halevi and Hugo Krawczyk in 2007;

- [Strengthening Digital Signatures via Randomized Hashing](https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2006/41170039/41170039.pdf)

For MD based hash functions. They defined the Target Collision Resistant (TCR) as;

> a family of hash functions $\{H_r\}_r\in R$ (for some set $R$) is target collision-resistant if no efficient attacker $A$ can win the following game, except with insignificant probability:

> - A chooses a first message $M$, then receives a random value $r \in_R R$, and it needs to find a second message $M' \neq M$ such that $H_r(M_0) = H_r(M)$. The value $r$ is called a hashing key, or a salt.

and they also defined the Enhanced Target Collision Resistant (eTCR) since signature schemes like DSA don't support to sign the salt $r$. To support this they use relaxing the conditions to strengthen the mode of operation. This scheme is

> sufficiently strong to ensure the security of the resultant signatures even if we only apply the underlying signature to $H_r(M )$ and do not sign the salt $r$.

The game is played as;

> - A chooses a first message $M$, then receives a random value $r \in_R R$, the salt r, the attacker can supply a second message $M'$ and a second salt $r'$, and it is considered successful if $(r, M ) \neq (r', M' )$ but $H_r (M ) = H_{r'} (M')$.

and it needs to find a second message $M' \neq M$ such that $H_r(M_0) = H_r(M)$. The value $r$ is called a hashing key, or a salt.

They define two methods as;

1. $$H_r^c(m_1, \ldots , m_L) \overset{def}{=} H^c(m_1 \oplus r,\ldots, m_L\oplus r).$$ This scheme is TCR under second-preimage resisantce (SPR)
   <sup>*</sup>. This suit RSA signature since we can extend the modulus so that the $r$ can be signed, too.
2. And the below scheme is eCTR under SPR, too <sup>*</sup>, This is useful for DSA like algorithms in which signing additional data, $r$, is not easy.

   $$\tilde{H_r^c}(M)\overset{def}{=} H_r^c(0|M)  = H^c(r, m_1 \oplus r,\ldots, m_L\oplus r).$$

They designed their scheme so that the security of the resultant signature scheme does not depend on the resistance of the hash function to off-line collision attacks. *In short*, they related the security of their scheme to the second-preimage resistance of the compression functions.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> Actually, the proofs rely on two properties that related to SPR. e-SPR is the real hardness of collision resistance of $H_r$ and $\tilde{H_r}$. And, c-SPR, which is related to the *hierarchy of collision resistance*.</sub>

**Note 1:** There is a [web page](https://crypto.stanford.edu/firefox-rhash/) that shows how this and similar method can be easily applied to NSS Library and Firefox.

**Note 2:** The extended version of the paper is [here](http://www.ee.technion.ac.il/%7Ehugo/rhash/rhash.pdf) ( and it is not https!)

Comment: The proof is long. Maybe someone has a short answer...